# How to authenticate firebase user in google cloud shell

Tags: javascript, android, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am sending my data from firestore to algolia. Before sending that I have to set that data from firestore to google cloud platform. For that I ran following commands on google cloud shell terminal:
**firebase login**
Then it gave me this messsage: 
**Firebase optionally collects CLI usage and error reporting information to help improve our products. Data is collected in accordance with Google's privacy policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy) and is not used to identify you.** 
Then it asked for **Allow Firebase to collect CLI usage and error reporting information?**. I replied yes. Then it gave me a link to authenticate the account. After clicking on that link, it gave an error message.
[This is the error message which I recieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0aBY.png)
How to resolve this error? I tried many tutorials  but could not find any solution. i tried this link.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#handlingtheresponse

Comment: I would suggest to copy paste the link, as sometimes not whole is copied when clicked... Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is happened on my side as well.

When the link has been displayed in console part of it wasn't detected by the terminal application. As the result it opened in web browser just as a part of the link. If analyze whole link you will see that near the end of the link there is something like `response_type=`. If this part is missing this error massage is shown.

I hope it will help!